Android - What is the target-script-min.js Script Connected from 192.168.1.128:8080?
I have taken over an Android Application project with no documentation.  The original developer is unknown.
It's actually a Cordova Android Application.
Inside the <head> section of the main HTML file, there is the following line:
<script type="text/javascript" src="//192.168.1.128:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>

From some scant information from searching over the web, I gather it is involved in debug support.
Can somebody give me more information on what this is about and what is it to be used for?
I'm using chrome://inspect for debugging, which seems just fine.  Do I need this script or can I just remove this line altogether?

This?

@Teemu - Yes, I came across that too.  A lot of  the referenced links are broken and overall, it seems a bit terse.  It would be great to get a good explanation.

Weinre looks like an abandoned project, even the documentation page is dead. There's this docs, though.

There was at some point a javascript file hosted on the local network at the address 192.168.1.128:8080. This would not work in a production environment, as that endpoint would be out of reach. This might have been for dev/debug purposes, and would only work if the app is connected to the same network.
More over, Cordova's webview is now served over https, and so the endpoint would need to have an SSL certificate...
